# Question regarding Jinns, angels, and water

Tags: quran, hadith, salat, tafseer, food

Salam everyone. Holy Quran 21.30 says everything is made of water. Holy Quran 15:27 says Jinns were created from fire. Also, it is said that Angels are made of light and cannot eat or drink. I also know that fire has water vapor in it, but I don't think that is 100% water. My question is how does this work. How could everything be made of water if Jinns and Angels aren't? I also read another definition that said everything is dependent on water but Angels can't eat. Can anyone answer me.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 1):

Angels are made of light “ noor” they are created only to obey Allahs commends. They have no free will. They don’t eat , sleep or have any human functions . They only submit to Allahs will.

Jinn are made of smokeless fire and they have free will like humans . They also have religions and they live like human beings but in different dimension. They are good ones and bad ones , believers and non believers.

Humans are made out clay from molded mud.

Chapter 15 ( the rock )
27. And the jinn We created before, from piercing fire.
28. Your Lord said to the angels, “I am creating a human being from clay, from molded mud.”

And every living thing on earth made of water ;

30. Do the disbelievers not see that the heavens and the earth were one mass, and We tore them apart? And We made from water every living thing. Will they not believe?